# Error in VueStoreFront integration with Shopify

Tags: vue.js, shopify, vue-storefront

I'm trying to install `VueStoreFront` with `Shopify`. I have followed the installtion steps in https://docs.vuestorefront.io/v2/general/installation.html for Store front and

https://github.com/vuestorefront/shopify for Shopify instance and provided my shopify url and key. When running the application in the browser, I'm getting the below error.
[image]

and in the terminal the below error is thrown.

[image]

any idea on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an application error and it is resolved by now. Sorry for troubles! We made sure it won't happen again!

Please generate your project from the CLI again. Also, in case of any further questions you'll get the fastest answers by asking them on our [discord](https://discord.vuestorefront.io)

Cheers!